# Rotating a simple cube twice

Tags: javascript, three.js, blender

I have some experience on Blender 3d, but almost none on 3d programing and I've trying to work with `three.js` now.

My question is: I have a simple cube and I rotated it around `y-axis`; then I need to rotate it again around `y-axis`, but as if the axis was rotated too. On Blender I would press `RKEY` twice.

To rotate first time I used: `cube.rotation.y += Math.PI*.5;`

How can I do that in Three.js? I've tried some matrix transformations too, but I could get done.

--

@muimota help me with a jfiddle, then I'm completing my explanation below:

Thanks @muimota, this example will help me to explain what I'm trying to do! Here is a [changed fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3duardo/w5z6r686/1/) with a more clear explanation: the cube was rotated two times (y and z) and then will be rotated infinitely on `y axis`. What I trying to do is to make it always rotate parallels with one of its faces – just like first rotation was parallels to its top face.

Comment: `tree.js` or `three.js`?

Comment: Can you post some more code? It helps people to help you.

Answer (score 2):

If you rotate a cube 90º every frame it will look the same and you might think it didn't rotate (but it did).

Here is an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/Lbabobdx/

```
function render() {

  //ROTATES 90º every frame looking the same
  mesh.rotation.y += Math.PI/2;

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @muimota, this example will help me to explain what I'm trying to do! Here is a [changed fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3duardo/w5z6r686/1/) with a more clear explanation: the cube was rotated two times (y and z) and then will be rotated infinitely on `y axis`. What I trying to do is to make it always rotate parallels with one of its faces – just like first rotation was parallels to its top face.

Comment: This is how I would achieve it.
http://jsfiddle.net/w5z6r686/3/
Could you please accept the answer as correct?